# Heating Surface

Tags: wire, heat

I'm working on a school project, which entails heating a polycarbonate surface to melt a small amount of snow accumulation on top of it. The polycarbonate surface is 2 ft x 2ft. Our original concept didn't work, so now we are trying to heat a grid of nichrome or copper wire, which will be touching the polycarbonate surface. We are trying to accomplish this by connecting it to a 12 V, 18 Ah Deep Cycle battery. None of us are very electrical savvy, so we are not sure if this will work or if its dangerous. Thanks!

Comment: you battery has about 12X18X3600 = 778kJ energy, that's enough to melt about 2kg of snow if used sparingly.

Comment: Just use a 12V "IR" flood or spot lamp. Aim it at the panel. No matter what you do, most of the energy is going to be converted to heat. So all you really have to do is make sure most of that heat is transferred to the plastic panel or to the snow. It would be more efficient to use a motorized arm to push the snow off rather than try to melt it.

Comment: Polycarbonate melting temperature is 155 °C.

Answer (score 1):

The battery can supply sufficient current (for a short while) to heat a wire white hot.

Copper wire will be such low resistance that the current will be very high and will therefore heat the wire very hot. If you regulate the current (with a resistor), actually most of the heat will be dissipated in that resistor.

Nichrome is probably a better choice. Can you calculate how much power (watts) you'll need to melt the snow ? Then choose a length of Nichrome that will use that much current from power = V^2/R, where V = 12 V, and R is the resistance of the Nichrome that you'll need.